# Spring and RabbitMQ prefetch issue on Docker

Tags: java, docker, jvm, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I have an Application which is running on Tomcat, java 8 and Linux. I have managed to port the application to Docker Container and run Tomcat on Docker. I have realized that when A message which is being send to RabbitMQ is not being fetched by the Application on the first initially and instead there should Always be a second Message in the same Queue  in order for the Consumer to fetch them both from Queue.

The application is written on Spring 4 and RabbitMQ is outside of container. Frustrating part is that the same application works when I run the application on a VM while the consumer will Fetch when there is more than One message in the Queue.
The prefetch is set to 1 and same config works on VM Linux. however On Docker this does not work. Are you guys aware of such issue on Docker containers?

The rabbitMQ management is showing me there is 0 Ready, 1 UnAcked and 1 In total. 
Could the be the behaviour of JVM on Docker?

Here is an example of log from AMQP Spring:

```
Retrieving delivery for Consumer@3a6237b3: tags=[{amq.ctag-DRCYJkVeEnTtN94Yuk-7dw=dispatcher.all}], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://user@192.168.1.5:5672/DEV-CI,17), conn: Proxy@45e9797b Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@43eb454d [delegate=amqp://user@192.168.1.5/DEV-CI, localPort= 60354], acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0|BlockingQueueConsumer:nextMessage:499|Pool-Executor-18
```

Here is the screenshot from the rabbitmq manager:

[image]

Docker container:

- linux: 16.04
- java:8
- tomcat:8
- RabbitMQ 3.6.5, Erlang 18.3
- Spring-amqp version: 1.7.6.RELEASE
- Docker Engine: 17.12.0-ce

Comment: I suggest turning on DEBUG logging and watch the message flow.

Comment: Don't put stuff like that in comments; it's unreadable in that format - edit the question instead - that's not enough log; we need to see more. Something must be consuming the message - you might need to use a network monitor such as WireShark to figure out what's going on.

Comment: That's different to your description; your question says 1 ready, 0 unacked; the image says 0 ready, 1 unacked. Again, more logs are needed to understand why you have an unacked message. You also need to provide information about RabbitMQ and Spring AMQP versions.

Comment: I am using following Loggs. Is there any other logs to monitor?
org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener
org.springframework.amqp
Also In the above I provided the versions

Comment: If the `org.springframework` logs don't provide any clues, you need to monitor the Docker interface with something like wireshark - it has a plugin to analyze amqp protocol. It's [well documented on the RabbitMQ site](https://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-wireshark.html).

Comment: Could this cause any instability on Docker apps when communicating with RabbitMq? 
WARNING: Your kernel does not support swap limit capabilities or the cgroup is not mounted. Memory limited without swap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused by ThreadPoolTaskExecutor and the thread was being recalled every minutes.
To solve the issue I removed setting Executor on RabbitMQ Connection Factory. 
connectionFactory.setExecutor(asyncTaskExecutor); is removed
The connectionFactory is CachingConnectionFactory

Probably I can continue tune the ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  to enhance the behaviour.
Following is the details of threadpool

```
corePoolSize = 1;

maxPoolSize = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

queueCapacity = 1;

setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
```